# Starting 7zip from QProcess gives error "cannot find archive"

Tags: qt, path, 7zip, qprocess

i am working on an application made with Qt5 that downloads a .zip-file to a temporary directory and extracts the .zip-file to a specified directory.

I already managed to download the .zip-file and now I'm trying to extract it using 7zip. I use QProcess to start 7Zip.

Here the file structure of my Qt-build-kit-thingy:

```
build-ExtractTest-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug
    7za.exe
    build
        ExtractTest.exe
```

Here is the code I use for starting the Process:

```
// assemble extraction command
QString extractProgram = "7za.exe";
QStringList extractArguments;
extractArguments << "x"; // extract files and directories
extractArguments << "-y"; // suppress questions
extractArguments << "-o\"" + installPath+"\""; // extract to installdir
extractArguments << "\""+currentPath +"\"";

std::cout << extractProgram.toStdString() << " " << extractArguments.join(" ").toStdString() << std::endl;

// start extraction
extractionProcess.start(extractProgram, extractArguments);
```

Here is the output of my program (I print all output of 7zip to stdout):

```
7za.exe x -y -o"D:\Projects\build-ExtractTest-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\BlaBla" "C:/Users/js/AppData/Local/Temp/eci2002win.zip"
started

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18


Error:
cannot find archive


0
```

However when I execute the command from console then 7zip works as expected:

```
D:\Projects\build-ExtractTest-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug>7za.exe x -y -o"D:\Projects\build-ExtractTest-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\BlaBla" "C:/Users/js/AppData/Local/Temp/eci2002win.zip"

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Temp\eci2002win.zip

Extracting  ECI-Target VisualLayout.csv
Extracting  DataSet CrossReference.xls
Extracting  ECI2002 RandomLayoutCmyk1485-LZW.tif
Extracting  ECI2002 VisualLayoutCmyk1485-LZW.tif
Extracting  ECI-Target RandomLayout.csv
Extracting  ColorTargetRecommendation.pdf
Extracting  SampleDataSet Sorted by ID.txt
Extracting  SampleDataSet Sorted by Loc.txt

Everything is Ok

Files: 8
Size:       1978871
Compressed: 504660
```

So my guess is there is a path problem when executing 7zip via QProcess. I could be wrong though. Anyone any ideas?

PS: I downloaded this random zip-file from here: http://www.eci.org/_media/downloads/eci_2002_target/eci2002win.zip

EDIT: I tried putting `QDir::toNativeSeparators()` around the paths to convert to Windows' path seperator:

```
extractArguments << "-o\"" + QDir::toNativeSeparators(installPath) + "\""; // extract to installdir
extractArguments << "\"" + QDir::toNativeSeparators(currentPath) + "\"";
```

This doesn't work either. Here is the new console output of my application:

```
7za.exe x -y -o"D:\Projects\ExtractTest\build-Verpacker2-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\BlaBla" "C:\Users\JanS\AppData\Local\Temp\eci2002win.zip"
started

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18


Error:
cannot find archive
```

Comment: You're passing a path to the archive with forward slashes / on Windows, that's not going to work.

Comment: That doesn't work either, see edit.

Comment: try removing "\"" from arglist - QProcess should normalize arguments on it's own

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Thank you Kamil. If you make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Kamil didn't answer, I give it myself:

The correct way to call 7zip is

```
7za.exe x -y "-oD:\Projects\ExtractTest\build-Verpacker2-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\BlaBla" "C:\Users\JanS\AppData\Local\Temp\eci2002win.zip"
```

7zip does not like the `"` after the `-o`.