# Use QProcess to unzip .Z file with 7z.exe, No Errors but also No output

Tags: c++, qt, 7zip, qprocess

I am using Qt 5.2.1 with MSVC 2010 on my Windows 8.1 computer. I am using QProcess to unzip a file. (Specifically a file I have downloaded from here ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gps/data/daily/2015/015/15n/  and the file is brdc0150.15n.Z) I am pointing to the executable correctly because I am getting no errors from starting the process. I don't get any errors but I do get this in my application output window when running in debug:

```
Application "\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" found in cache.
```

Here are the arguments that I pass to 7z.exe:

```
QProcess *extractProcess = new QProcess(this);
QString extractProgram = extractFilePath;

QStringList extractArguments;

QString dirPath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath());
extractArguments << "x"; // extract files and directories
extractArguments << "-y"; // suppress questions
extractArguments << "\"-o" + dirPath+"\\newFile.n"+"\""; // extract to installdir
extractArguments << "\""+dirPath+"\\"+zipfilename +"\"";


// start extraction
extractProcess->start(extractProgram, extractArguments);


if (!extractProcess->waitForFinished(30000))
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, tr("ERROR"), extractProcess->errorString());
```

The problem I am having seems identical to the one here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/43861/qprocess-application-found-in-cache, but there is no solution. Any ideas?? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you read this article? [The correct way to call 7zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897273/starting-7zip-from-qprocess-gives-error-cannot-find-archive)

Comment: Yes I have. That is actually how I got started. I am not getting the error that he or she was getting. I am getting no errors. And the problem that they have corrected is how I am currently doing things. What portion do you think I am not doing properly related to that post? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: 1. Did you try to specify a simple explicit path to the file? 2. Did you call [`readAllStandardError()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError) and [`readAllStandardOutput()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) ?

Comment: No need to create QProcess in heap. Also try to use unix separator. QProcess can convert it automatically. Also look at exitCode() value.
Most probably that you have wrong args.
https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract_full.htm

Comment: You were right! readAllStandardOutput() has an output. I thought the error would show up in error information. I didn't think I was getting the same error as the post you originally suggested, but it turns out you were right and I was having the exact same problem. Sorry about the confusion! Thanks again for the help!